# RDLC Report - How to access localized string values using custom code within the report

Tags: asp.net, webforms, rdlc, reportviewer

All,

I am upgrading from .net 2 to .net 4.6 but I have an issue with my RDLC (ie. local) reports.

Specifically, my RDLC reports reference code from one of my assemblies which performs access to language specific .resx files. This allows me to create report expressions that reference language specific strings, words, in a language independent way.

Everything worked great until we switched from .net 2 to .net 4. With the new CAS changes I was forced to rewrite code that specificially adds an assembly reference from this:

```
report.AddTrustedCodeModuleInCurrentAppDomain();
```

to this:

```
SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain();
AddFullTrustModuleInSandboxAppDomain();
```

But now I have observed that this causes my custom DLL to load 2nd time into the report without current HTTP context. Without current HTTP context I have no way to access my string .resx files via:

```
String localizedValue =
                (string)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(
                    resourceFile, resourceKey);
```

Therefore, I have some options but need guidance how to accomplish these:

**BTW, passing lang specific string via parameters is not an option really because I have lots of strings, that would mean lots of custom parameters.**

1) Another way to retrieve lang specific strings from inside my .resx files (is there another method I can call without HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject)? Or I have to manually code loading .resx files and parsing them (that would be lots of work)

2) Somehow get current HTTP context in my report's context. I tried to be clever here and created a static ctor where I initialized my static variable to current HTTP context. Unfortunately, this will not work because when the report engine evaluates the expressions in the report it appears that it loads another version of the same assembly (observed as I was debugging it).

3) Another solution as suggested by you.

Comment: Cant you use the ResourceManager class to do this?

Comment: I don't mind trying, you have a link to an example? FYI: My resource strings are in separate .resx files.

Comment: I've never done it, however, it seems plausible... When you reference an assembly in your report, it has to be deployed to and accessed from the ReportServer\bin folder. Could you throw your satellite assemblies and resx lang folders inside that bin folder and then create a wrapper to call upon the ResourceManager as you would in a windows application, bypassing the need of HttpClient? The only way to do this in your web application would be to do some hackish post render processing when the report payload is returned.

Comment: OK, so I tried your suggestion and got it to work as follows:
1) I moved the strings to a satellite assembly and loaded that assembly via ResourceManager resm = new ResourceManager("myns.mystrings", Assembly.Load()); 
You do not need any resource files copying with this approach because the ResourceManager only extracts embeded resources from an assembly. This works, it is not ideal because I would have to move my strings to a satelite assembly. Interestingly, I could not extract the resource string from my app root assembly (I wonder if App_GlobalResources has something to do with it)

Comment: If I am understanding what you are asking about App_GlobalResources...Don't those get precompiled into their own binary and deployed/shipped and if so, since RS has already been compiled how will you merge your resources with RS's own resources?

Comment: Yes, code behinds of .resx files get compiled into the web app's assembly,- unfortunately creating resource manager the same way "ResourceManager resm = new ResourceManager("myns.mystrings", Assembly.Load())" as in the example of satellite assembly and calling resm.GetString() throws MissingManifestException although I did embed .resx file as a resource (ie. its missing the embedded .resource file). Btw, I am not using RS, I am using client side reports which are generated view reportviewer control on the server.

Comment: OK, so I read that resources in App_GlobalResources are compiled to a separate assembly and are internal in scope. Therefore, accessing these from another assembly is not possible not knowing the hashed assembly name. Satellite assembly is pretty much the best solution I got in this case unless there's another way to get access to the lang resource files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring various possible possibilities the most elegant solution is to create a satellite assembly of language strings and then use the ResourceManager class as suggested to load the assembly and retrieve the strings from another assembly.

FYI:
For this to work you need to have the satellite assembly in the bin folder.